# Swing -- background colour only shown if selected?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Alright, so I have an `IndirectListModel<MyRow>` allowing for multi-selection of rows that I bind to a `JTable`, all cells of which I set the following renderer for:

```java
private static class MyVerificationHighlightingCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, rowIndex, columnIndex);

        MyRow row = ...

        if (row.isValid()) {
            setBackground(Background.OK);

        } else {
            setBackground(Background.ERROR);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

This works ... ONLY when the rows are selected.

I.e. I select rows, they turns either green or red, depending on their `isValid()` methods. However, as soon as I select something else, the new selection gets the background colours and the others go back to white/ striped.

Why? And more importantly, how can I make my table use the darn colours I want it to have when the rows are NOT selected?

Comment: It would be great if you could give us a [mcve].

Comment: @GeorgeZ. would love to ... except I'm not allowed to.

Comment: (1-) *except I'm not allowed to* - of course you are. The point of the [mre] is to demonstrate the problem. There is no need for you to post real data. We are just asking for a frame with a JList and a custom render. There is nothing proprietary about that.

Comment: This is JGoodies-specific behavior, not pure Swing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what happens is that we're using the `JGStripedTable` class in the background. This thing generates the stripes that normally get displayed.

We need to tell it NOT to do that by adding

```
putClientProperty("JGoodies.customBackground", true);
```

into our `getTableCellRendererComponent` method before we return.